# Very strange File reading output Java

Tags: java, file, arraylist, io

So, I read words from an text file and save them in an ArrayList of ArrayLists. It should print the words exactly as they are in the file. For example:

```
test1 test2 test3 test4 test5
test6 test7 test8
test9 test10
```

But it prints this: [Actual output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pEyF.jpg)
Why does it behave like that and how to fix it?
Here is the reading code:

```java
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordOrder {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> LinesList;
    public ArrayList<String> Words_per_line_list;
    protected String FileName;
    protected File file;
    public WordOrder(){
        LinesList = new ArrayList<>();
        Words_per_line_list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
public void wordReading() throws IOException, IndexOutOfBoundsException{
        String word_to_be_read;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println ("Enter the name of the file");
            FileName = scan.nextLine ();
            file = new File(FileName);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (FileName));
            if(in.read () == -1){
                throw new IOException ("File does not exist or cannot be accessed");
            }
            System.out.println ("Test");
            int i =0, j = 0;
            while(in.readLine() != null) {
                LinesList.add(i, Words_per_line_list);
                while ((in.read ()) != -1) {
                    word_to_be_read = in.readLine ();
                    Words_per_line_list.add(j, word_to_be_read);
                    System.out.println (LinesList.get (i).get (j));
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are LinesList and Words_per_line_list? You don't show their definition / creation.

Comment: @pcoates These are two ArrayLists. LinesList is a List of Lists, while Words_per_line_list is a List of Strings. It is akin to: ``` LinesList<Words_per_line_list<String>>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while statements are reading data, but you're not doing anything with that data..

The first `while(in.readLine() != null) {` will read the first line from your file

i.e. test1 test2 test3 test4 test5

but you don't do anything with it.

the second `while ((in.read ()) != -1) {` will read a single character from the file. So the `t` leaving `est6 test7 test8` to be read by `word_to_be_read = in.readLine ();`, then again the `t` from the next line, leaving `est9 test10` for the next `readline`

You can read the line into a variable in the outer while, then just process the line however you need to inside the while loop.

```
String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // process the line however you need to
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have one more question. What condition should I set in the ```while(in.readLine() != null)```, so as to iterate until EOF?

Comment: Checking for != null will iterate until EOF. 
From the javadoc... readline() `Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), a carriage return followed immediately by a line feed, or by reaching the end-of-file (EOF).` and also `returns null if the end of the stream has been reached without reading any characters`